# Cause TableView to not respond to mouse clicks in JavaFX 2.0

Tags: java, javafx-2, selectionmodel

I want a JavaFX 2.0 TableView, but I don't want it to respond to mouse clicks.  Of course, I can disable the control/widget but then it appears disabled.

tableview.setSelectionModel(null) gives the behavior I'd like, but the UI dumps stack traces complaining about the null.  I can't catch the null.

I've been trying to create some kind of SelectionModel or TableViewSelectionModel that has some methods gutted, so it doesn't respond.  I'm having a hard time extending these classes or implementing abstracts.

Ideas on disabling clicks on TableViews?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[tableView.setMouseTransparent(true)](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#setMouseTransparent%28boolean%29)

Comment: Thank you for saving me from myself.  An oddly named method.

Comment: If the component gets focus using something like Tab, then the user is able to use arrow keys to select rows or cells. This isn't exactly what I had in mind.  A work around: tableView.setFocusTraversable(false)

Comment: Is there a way I can disable selecting the rows, while still allowing vertical scrolling?

Comment: Please ask a new question James.